# VS code pyperclip Import "pyperclip" could not be resolved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyperclip

I am trying to use pyperclip for a python course I am doing and it tells me to import pyperclip, but when I import it VS code says Import "pyperclip" could not be resolved even though I went into the terminal and installed it my python version is 3.10.6 64bit does anyone know how to fix this?

```py
pip install pyperclip
```

Comment: have you tried running a python file with import pyperclip? and see whether it stops at the import?

Comment: Are you familiar with virtual environments? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments. Did you install pyperclip in the virtual environment, you are using in VS Code?

Comment: I ran another code that has import pyperclip and it will stop and give me the errors saying import could not be resolved

Comment: Okay, but does it work when run from the terminal, the same place you installed pyperclip? If so, pyperclip is installed in that Python environment, but not in whatever environment VSCode is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps below to choose an interpreter

1. Open the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search for **Python:Select Interpreter**
3. Choose the correct interpreter

**It is recommended to use a virtual environment**

*use the following command in the vscode terminal:*

- Create a virtual environment ( named **.venv** )

  ```
  python -m venv .venv
  ```
- Activate the virtual environment

  ```
  .venv/Scripts/Activate
  ```
- Select the interpreter in the virtual environment
- Create a new terminal to automatically activate the virtual environment
- Install the packages you need to use in the current environment

*Virtual environments can help you manage using different python versions and using different packages.*